# I'm stuck in Vim; I see "Command Line" at the bottom and nothing makes Vim respond

Tags: command-line, quit

I pressed `:wq` to write and quit.

Except now I see a `Command Line` at the bottom and nothing I do makes `vi` respond (<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, etc.). How do I get back to civilisation from here? If you can save my file at the same time, bonus! Otherwise, I'll try editing it again... if I can ever exit!

Comment: That's annoying! It unfroze itself (and deleted the contents, but didn't save it) while I was asking this question. Apparently you need to ask a question on this site to get it to work again... Answers still welcome for next time!

Comment: Assuming you are using `vim` in a terminal, not `gvim`: could you have press `Ctrl+s` by accident, thus freezing the terminal? This would have rendered `vi` irresponsive. If that was the case, you could have used `Ctrl+q` to unfreeze.

Comment: @guillem How can I tell if `vi` runs vi or vim... or gvim?

Comment: The command `:echo has('gui_running')` shows `1` for `gvim`, and `0` for `vim`. Furthermore, `gvim` does not freeze by pressing `Ctrl+s`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Carpetsmoker. However, you deleted the bit that I pressed a whole bunch of other keys first. I think that was important.

Answer (score 5):

You probably pressed `q:` instead of `:q`. The `q:` command opens the commandline window.

You can close it like any other window by using `:q`, `:close`, or `<C-w>w`.

Some people like to disable this mapping:

```
:nnoremap q: <Nop>
```

Or have it auto-correct to `:q`:

```
:nnoremap q: :q
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are in Ex mode? You can get there by typing `Q` in command mode. Type `:visual` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit from it.